# How to sort each row in a 2d String array in java using Arrays.sort?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to sort each row of a 2d String array in java.

**Example**:

For example, if an array contains:

```
ZCD
BFE
DZA
```

I want it to be sorted as:

```
CDZ
BEF
ADZ
```

**Code**:

```
private String[] commonCollections;

private int comparisons = 0;

public Comparable[] findCommonElements(Comparable[][] collections){

    for(int i = 0; i < collections.length; i++){
        Arrays.sort(collections[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <collections[0].length; i++){
        System.out.print(collections[0][i] + "\n");
    }

    return commonCollections;
}
```

Thanks. With the code above, its not sorting for some reason.

Comment: What does that output? If you're referring to it returning an empty array, its because you are returning an empty array. You don't initialize commonCollections. Please be clear about what you mean.

Comment: How are you storing the element..We can assume and answer..better to come from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sorting seems fine. The way you are printing is the issue.

Is this what you want?

```
public class Main {


    public  static Comparable[][] findCommonElements(Comparable[][] collections){


        for(int i = 0; i < collections.length; i++){
            Arrays.sort(collections[i]);

        }

        return collections;
    } 

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Character [][]input= {{'Z','C','D'},{'B','F','E'},{'D','Z','A' }};

    Comparable[][] output = findCommonElements(input);

    for(int i = 0; i <output.length; i++){
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(output[i]) + "\n");
    }     
  }
}
```

Which produces this output:

[C, D, Z]  [B, E, F] [A, D, Z]

Comment: Hey nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

You've almost done it, you can fix your code by debugging.

Here is an approach with java8 streams

```
    char[][] arr = { { 'Z', 'C', 'D' }, { 'B', 'F', 'E' }, { 'D', 'Z', 'A' } };
    char[][] sorted = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).mapToObj(i -> arr[i]).peek(x -> Arrays.sort(x)).toArray(char[][]::new);
    for (char[] js : sorted)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(js));
```

output

```
[C, D, Z]
[B, E, F]
[A, D, Z]
```